# Watermark on pdf not working properlly

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am creating pdf using itextsharp. Now I want to add watermark on each pages I tried  method on

```
public override void OnStartPage(PdfWriter wr, iTextSharp.text.Document doc)
```

Now watermark is coming but if pdf page containing image then its hiding watermark

```
public class itsevent : PdfPageEventHelper
{
    string watermarkText = string.Empty;
    public itsevent(string watermark)
    {
        watermarkText = watermark;
    } 

    public override void OnStartPage(PdfWriter wr, iTextSharp.text.Document doc)
    {
        float fontSize = 80;
        float xPosition = 300;
        float yPosition = 300;
        float angle = 45;
        PdfContentByte u = wr.DirectContentUnder;
        PdfGState gs = new PdfGState();
        u.SaveState();
        u.SetGState(gs);
        BaseFont baseFont =BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        u.BeginText();
        u.SetColorFill(iTextSharp.text.pdf.CMYKColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
        u.SetFontAndSize(baseFont, fontSize);
        u.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, watermarkText, xPosition, yPosition, angle);
        u.EndText();
        under.RestoreState();
    } 
}

itsevent ev = new itsevent("watermark");
pdfW.PageEvent = ev;
doc.Open();
```

Comment: **A** you use `wr.DirectContentUnder` which is for adding content **under** the normally added content. Thus, obviously an image there will cover the watersign. Use `wr.DirectContent` instead. **B** you are adding stuff in `OnStartPage`; iText developers recommend against doing so. Instead do that in `OnEndPage` **C** You might want to apply transparency in `PdfGState gs`.

Comment: u caught it great...  now its working thankss alott.

Comment: Wonderful. I'll make it an answer.

Answer (score 2):

### Which `PdfContentByte` to use

You use `wr.DirectContentUnder` which is for adding content under the normally added content:

```
PdfContentByte u = wr.DirectContentUnder;
```

Thus, obviously an image in the normal content will cover the watersign. Use `wr.DirectContent` instead.

### Which page event to use

You are adding the watermark in `OnStartPage`; iText developers recommend against doing so. Instead do that in `OnEndPage`.

### How to improve the looks

You might want to apply transparency by setting the fill opacity of `PdfGState gs`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `GetOverContext()` to get the image 
https://simpledotnetsolutions.wordpress.com/2012/04/08/itextsharp-few-c-examples/

Comment: getovercontext() is not finding which refrence it needs

Comment: @KratikaSharma you need to show more code samples to understand what is wrong.

Comment: is there any other way to paste my code. bcz my code is going out of limit

Comment: public override void OnStartPage(PdfWriter wr, iTextSharp.text.Document doc)
{float fontSize = 80;float xPosition = 300;float yPosition = 300;float angle = 45;
PdfContentByte u = wr.DirectContentUnder;
PdfGState gs = new PdfGState();
u.SaveState();
u.SetGState(gs);
BaseFont baseFont =BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
u.BeginText();
u.SetColorFill(iTextSharp.text.pdf.CMYKColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
u.SetFontAndSize(baseFont, fontSize);
u.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, watermarkText, xPosition, yPosition, angle);
u.EndText();under.RestoreState();}

Comment: public class itsevent : PdfPageEventHelper
    {
        string watermarkText = string.Empty;

        public itsevent(string watermark)
        {
            watermarkText = watermark;
        }

Comment: itsevent ev = new itsevent("watermark");
            pdfW.PageEvent = ev;
            doc.Open();

Comment: @KratikaSharma try using Pastebin

Comment: @KratikaSharma Please Google for it.

Comment: *is there any other way to paste my code.* - even better than pastebin: add the relevant code to your question. There is an edit link...